# Configure imports relative to root directory in create-react-library library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, rollup

I am trying to setup a react component library with create-react-library (which uses rollup under the hood) and port over our application's existing component library so that we can share it between applications. I am able to create the library, publish to a private git registry, and consume it in other applications. The issue is that I have had to change all of my imports to relative imports which is rather annoying as I am planning on porting over a large amount of components, hocs and utils.

The entry point of the package is the `src` dir. Say I have a component in `src/components/Text.js` and a hoc in `src/hoc/auth.js`. If I want to import `withAuthentication` from `src/hoc/auth.js` into my Text component, I have to import it like `import { withAuthentication } from "../hoc/auth"` but I'd like to be able to import with the same paths I have in my existing application so it's easy to port over components, like `import { withAuthentication } from "hoc/auth"`

I have tried a lot of config options, jsconfig.json the same as my create-react-app application, manually building my library with rollup rather then using create-react-library so I'd have more config options but to no avail.

Below are the relevant bits from my package.json as well as my jsconfig.json, any help would be greatly appreciated, I am sure I am not the only person who's had this issue.

Here's the package.json

```
{
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.modern.js",
  "source": "src/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "microbundle-crl --no-compress --format modern,cjs",
    "start": "microbundle-crl watch --no-compress --format modern,cjs",
    "prepare": "run-s build",
    "test": "run-s test:unit test:lint test:build",
    "test:build": "run-s build",
    "test:lint": "eslint .",
    "test:unit": "cross-env CI=1 react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "test:watch": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "predeploy": "cd example && npm install && npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d example/build"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-localstorage": "^0.4.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "react-svg": "^12.0.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "microbundle-crl": "^0.13.10",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.7.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-react": "^9.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.17.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "gh-pages": "^2.2.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^7.0.0"
  }
}
```

and here's the jsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use aliases? They can be setup in `tsconfig.paths`. They are not supported in ReactCreatApp but might be supported in RCL. Would you like to use relative paths only internally within the library or in the consumer?

Comment: I haven't tried using aliases, and would prefer not to, I'd like it to "just work" as I am porting over a ton of components, I'd like to keep the overhead to a minimum. Paths should be relative within the library.

Comment: I tried as you suggested, unfortunately it's not supported by the library

Answer (score 1):

The example from the following link maybe you should navigate to your src file from the BaseUrl, or if you "src" is in the same directory as your config it should be only "."

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping

Example from link above:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".", // This must be specified if "paths" is.
    "paths": {
      "jquery": ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery"] // This mapping is relative to "baseUrl"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I have tried several different config options, but it seems that microbundle-crl doesn't support or ignores them. There are microbundle arguments such as --alias, --cwd that I have tried to use and those don't seem to work either. Whatever I have tried, anything other than relative imports the bundler fails to find "X is imported by src/index.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency" etc.

Comment: added comments to this open issue on the create-react-library github page:
https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/create-react-library/issues/300

Comment: Also, options I tried from your suggestion (several combinations of the following fields):
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "rootDirs": ["src/components"],
        "paths": {
            "\*": ["\*"]
        }

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 3 things

**tsconfig.json** this enables typescript autocomplete

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["./src/*"],
      "src": ["./src"]
    }
  }
}
```

**babel.config.js** this plugin resolves relative modules

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        alias: {
          src: './src'
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

**package.json** // install babel-plugin-module-resolver

```
{
  //...
  "devDependencies": {
    //...
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0",
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, was able to follow your suggestions to add aliases for the rest of the directories I want to import from, much cleaner and less of a headache to port over components to the library now. I am still unable to see autocompletion of imports in VS Code for some reason but will play around with it.